# Remove class objects generated by css-loader when using css-modules

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, css-modules, css-loader

Currently when the `modules:  true` option is defined in `css-loader` configuration, a json object is added to js output for each css file. E.g

input

```
// style.css

.has-spinner {

}
```

output

```
// style.css (in js bundle)
{
  hasSpinner: 'someHashedCssModuleClass',
}
```

and then, in my case, it will be referenced by some React component:

```
// someComponent.js
<SomeComponent className={styles.hasSpinner}
```

I'm wondering if there is any loader/plugin that is capable of inlining the generated css properties and removing the json object like so:

```
// style.css
.someHashedCssModuleClass {

}
```

```
// someComponent.js
<SomeComponent className="someHashedCssModuleClass"
```

So that bundle size can be reduced.

Comment: This is its advantage. Random hashes are produced every time you compile to avoid style conflicts.

Comment: @weiliang yeah I get that, but wouldn't it be better to modify the class name both inline and in the stylesheet to avoid having large json objects clogging up the js bundles?

Comment: how about https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/? If you care about performance you should be using this plugin for your css

Comment: @RazRonen yes I'm using css-extract-plugin to extract the css into seperate files but you are still left with these json objects when using css modules